# Why do different machine learning methods give the same variable importance, in caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, party

I am comparing different machine learning methods using caret, but though the methods are very different, I am getting identical variable contributions.

vNNet, ctree, enet, knn, M5, pcr, ridge, svmRadial give the same variable contributions.

Some of these will take importance = TRUE as input: vNNet, enet, knn, pcr, ridge, svmRadial do.
Others generated an error with importance = TRUE: ctree, M5.
(The error is "Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:")

My question is why do different methods give the same variable importance?
This seems wrong, but I can't see what I've done wrong.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
library(elasticnet)
library(party)

data_set <- diamonds[1:1000, c(1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)]
formula <- price ~ carat + depth + table + x + y + z

set.seed(100)
enet_model <- train(formula,
                    importance = TRUE,
                    data = data_set,
                    method = "enet",
                    trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"),
                    preProc = c("center", "scale"))

set.seed(100)
ctree_model <- train(formula, 
                     data = data_set,
                     method = "ctree",
                     trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))

set.seed(Set_seed_seed)
knn_model <- train(formula,
                   importance = TRUE,
                   data = data_set,
                   method = "knn",
                   preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                   tuneGrid = data.frame(k = 1:20),
                   trControl = training_control)

varImp(enet_model)
varImp(ctree_model)
varImp(knn_model)
```

I'm using caret 6.0-52

Comment: We don't have access to `data_set_train`.

Comment: Sorry, should have been data_set. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?varImp`:

> For models that do not have corresponding `varImp` methods, see `filterVarImp`.

Those methods don't have importance scores implemented so you get model-free measures. I can add one for `enet` based on the coefficient values but `knn` and `ctree` have no obvious methods.

Comment: Thanks topepo! That makes sense. The list is ones from Applied Predictive Modelling in the regression section. The other methods in the book without importance scores are avNNet, M5, pcr, ridge and svmRadial